# How can I get customer custom attributes from $order?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, orders, customer

I need to get custom attributes from my customers using the `$order` object.

I tried to do something like `$order->getCustomerCustomAttribute();` for a `custom_attribute` but it didn`t worked. Is there a specific format to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get customer infromation from order, you need to do this code.

```
$customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
echo $customer->getCustomAttribute();
```